# Python / Kivy Global variables not working/accessible

Tags: python, variables, button, global, kivy

I am now struggling since weeks on one Problem. I have a code for a very simple Alarm Device. It receives TCP Notifications from my Axis Cameras and plays a sound and also lights up my Hella Rotary LED Signal Lamps.
For this purpose I took a raspberry with a touchscreen and built it into a housing with a relay-output via GPIO.

[Beedo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXMne.jpg)

I also have some Kivy buttons that should enable/disable the alarms.
A kivy button is executing Functions ; the functions set a variable. BUT the variable is ONLY being changed IN the class with the Kivy app but not outside.

I also made a seperate Variant where the complete code is in one class - also not working.
The variable `power` is never beeing changed and always keeps its value `1` in function `do_pseudo_blinken`. Please - has somebody an idea? Thank you!

Variant 2 - Everything in one class `MainApp`:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python2
# Beedo v110 8.4.2016
# mit Sound!

import sys
import time
import datetime
import socket
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
#from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App
#import var
import kivy
import os
#--------------------------------------------
#import RPi.GPIO as GPIO                        # import GPIO library  - auskommentiert fuer Tests auf Windows

class MainApp(App):
global power
power = 1
global timestamp

def build(self):
    return Builder.load_file("beedo_111_test.kv")

#---------------------------------------------------
#        Kivy Callback functions
#---------------------------------------------------

def callback_power_0(self):
    global power
    power = 0

    print "Power =", power

def callback_power_1(self):
    global power
    power = 1
    print "Power =", power
#------------------------------------------------
def callback_terrasse_0(self):
    terrasse=0
    print "Terrasse =", terrasse

def callback_terrasse_1(self):
    terrasse=1
    print "Terrasse =", terrasse
#------------------------------------------------
def callback_umseck_0(self):
    umseck=0
    print "umseck =", umseck

def callback_umseck_1(self):
    umseck=1
    print "umseck =", umseck
#------------------------------------------------
def callback_eingang_0(self):
    eingang=0
    print "eingang =", eingang

def callback_eingang_1(self):
    eingang=1
    print "eingang =", eingang
#------------------------------------------------
def callback_strasse_0(self):
    strasse=0
    print "strasse =", strasse

def callback_strasse_1(self):
    strasse=1
    print "strasse =", strasse
#------------------------------------------------
def callback_pieplang_0(self):
    pieplang=0
    print "pieplang =", pieplang

def callback_pieplang_1(self):
    pieplang=1
    print "pieplang =", pieplang

#------------------------------------------------
#===============================================================================

def timestamp():
    fmt = "%H:%M:%S (%d.%m.%Y)" # 14:16:23 (24.03.2016)
    #return time.strftime(fmt, time.gmtime(time.time())) #hat falsche Zeit ausgegeben
    return time.strftime(fmt, time.localtime(time.time()))

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def socket_server(self, host, port, event_queue, num):
    global zeit
    #localtime = time.asctime( time.localtime(time.time()) )
    print "socketserver startet ..", port
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    try:
        s.bind((host, port))
    except socket.error as msg:
        print("Binding to the port %d failed." % port)
        print("Error Code: " + str(msg[0]) + " Message " + msg[1])
        sys.exit()

    s.listen(10)
    print "listening on Port", port
    while True:
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        event = (addr[0], timestamp(), num)
        event_queue.put(event)
        conn.close()

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def do_blinken ():                  #laesst Rundumlicht und LED aufleuchten, und gibt kurzen Piepston
    GPIO.output(23, True)
    GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(24, True)
    GPIO.output(25, True)
    time.sleep(0.508)
    GPIO.output(25, False)
    time.sleep(4)
    GPIO.output(24, False)
    GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.IN)
    GPIO.output(23, False)
    return

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def do_pseudo_blinken (self):                  #Pseudo-Blinkfunktion auf (Windows)
    print "power =", power
    print "blinken beginnt"
    time.sleep(2)
    print "blinken endet"
    return

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def do_sound (self, n):                          #spielt sound ab der in "IP_NAME" definiert ist
    print "spiele sound ab fuer", n
    #os.system("omxplayer -o local --no-osd --vol -1200 %s >/dev/null" %(n))
    print "sound abgespielt fuer ", n
    return

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def event_handler(self, event_queue, ip_name):
    print ("handler startet..")
    #GPIO.cleanup()                  #setzt generelle GPIO Parameter - auskommentiert fuer Tests auf Windows
    #GPIO.setwarnings(False)         #setzt generelle GPIO Parameter - auskommentiert fuer Tests auf Windows
    #GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)          #setzt generelle GPIO Parameter - auskommentiert fuer Tests auf Windows
    #GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.OUT)        #setzt generelle GPIO Parameter - auskommentiert fuer Tests auf Windows
    #GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.IN)         #setzt generelle GPIO Parameter - auskommentiert fuer Tests auf Windows
    #GPIO.setup(25, GPIO.OUT)        #setzt generelle GPIO Parameter - auskommentiert fuer Tests auf Windows
    print ("handler gestartet")
    while True:
        try:
            event = event_queue.get(timeout=10)
            camera, n = ip_name[event[0]][event[2]-1]

            #---------------------------------------------------
            print("%s ---> %s" % (camera, event[1]))
            blinken1 = Process (target=MainApp().do_pseudo_blinken, args=())        #ruft Funktion fuer Beedo-blinken auf (RAspberry)
            sound1 = Process (target=MainApp().do_sound, args=(n,))

            #blinken1 = Process (target=do_pseudo_blinken, args=())  #ruft Pseudo-Blinkfunktion auf (Windows)


            blinken1.start()
            sound1.start()
            time.sleep(0.6)
            sound1.terminate()
            #print MainApp.power
            #---------------------------------------------------
        except:
            pass

    #===============================================================================

if __name__ == "__main__":

#Window.size = (800, 480)

#------------------- config data ---------------
HOST = "0.0.0.0"
PORT1 = 47120
PORT2 = 47121
IP_NAME = {
    "192.168.1.202" : [("Umseck  ", "umseck.mp3")],
    "192.168.1.203" : [("Eingang ", "eingang4.mp3"), ("Strasse", "strasse.mp3")],
    "192.168.1.204" : [("Terrasse", "terrasse.mp3")],
    "192.168.1.100" : [("Test ", "umseck.mp3"), ("Test2 ", "terrasse.mp3")],
    "192.168.1.200" : [("Test ", "eingang2.mp3"), ("Test2 ", "strasse.mp3")],
    "192.168.1.201" : ["CCU2"],
    "127.0.0.1" : ["localhost"]
}


#-----------------------------------------------
EVENTS = Queue()
#-----------------------------------------------

server1 = Process (target=MainApp().socket_server, args=(HOST, PORT1, EVENTS, 1))
server2 = Process (target=MainApp().socket_server, args=(HOST, PORT2, EVENTS, 2))
handler = Process (target=MainApp().event_handler, args=(EVENTS, IP_NAME))

server1.start()
server2.start()
handler.start()

MainApp().run()

server1.join()
server2.join()
handler.join()
```

Variant 1 (original Code) - All function "outside" of the Kivy Class `MainApp`

```
#! /usr/bin/env python2
# Beedo v110 8.4.2016
# mit Sound!

import sys
import time
import socket
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
#from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App
#import var
import kivy
import os
#--------------------------------------------
#import RPi.GPIO as GPIO                        # import GPIO library  - auskommentiert fuer Tests auf Windows


#===============================================================================

def timestamp():
    fmt = "%H:%M:%S (%d.%m.%Y)" # 14:16:23 (24.03.2016)
    #return time.strftime(fmt, time.gmtime(time.time())) #hat falsche Zeit ausgegeben
    return time.strftime(fmt, time.localtime(time.time()))

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------


def socket_server(host, port, event_queue, num):
print "socketserver startet ..", port
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
try:
    s.bind((host, port))
except socket.error as msg:
    print("Binding to the port %d failed." % port)
    print("Error Code: " + str(msg[0]) + " Message " + msg[1])
    sys.exit()

s.listen(10)
print "listening on Port", port
while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    event = (addr[0], timestamp(), num)
    event_queue.put(event)
    conn.close()

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def do_blinken ():                  #laesst Rundumlicht und LED aufleuchten, und gibt kurzen Piepston
GPIO.output(23, True)
GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(24, True)
GPIO.output(25, True)
time.sleep(0.508)
GPIO.output(25, False)
time.sleep(4)
GPIO.output(24, False)
GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.output(23, False)
return

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def do_pseudo_blinken ():                  #Pseudo-Blinkfunktion auf (Windows)
print "power =", MainApp.power
print "blinken beginnt"
time.sleep(5)
print "blinken endet"
return

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def do_sound (n):                          #spielt sound ab der in "IP_NAME" definiert ist
print "spiele sound ab fuer", n
#os.system("omxplayer -o local --no-osd --vol -1200 %s >/dev/null" %(n))
print "sound abgespielt fuer ", n
return

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def event_handler(event_queue, ip_name):
    print ("handler startet..")
    #GPIO.cleanup()                  #setzt generelle GPIO Parameter - auskommentiert fuer Tests auf Windows
    #GPIO.setwarnings(False)         #setzt generelle GPIO Parameter - auskommentiert fuer Tests auf Windows
    #GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)          #setzt generelle GPIO Parameter - auskommentiert fuer Tests auf Windows
    #GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.OUT)        #setzt generelle GPIO Parameter - auskommentiert fuer Tests auf Windows
    #GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.IN)         #setzt generelle GPIO Parameter - auskommentiert fuer Tests auf Windows
    #GPIO.setup(25, GPIO.OUT)        #setzt generelle GPIO Parameter - auskommentiert fuer Tests auf Windows
print ("handler gestartet")
while True:
    try:
        event = event_queue.get(timeout=10)
        camera, n = ip_name[event[0]][event[2]-1]
        print("%s ---> %s" % (camera, event[1]))
        #---------------------------------------------------

        blinken1 = Process (target=do_pseudo_blinken, args=())        #ruft Funktion fuer Beedo-blinken auf (RAspberry)
        sound1 = Process (target=do_sound, args=(n,))
        #blinken1 = Process (target=do_pseudo_blinken, args=())  #ruft Pseudo-Blinkfunktion auf (Windows)


        blinken1.start()
        sound1.start()
        time.sleep(0.6)
        sound1.terminate()
        print MainApp.power
        #---------------------------------------------------
    except:
        pass

#===============================================================================

class MainApp(App):

power = 0

def build(self):
    return Builder.load_file("beedo_111.kv")

#---------------------------------------------------
#        Kivy Callback functions
#---------------------------------------------------

def callback_power_0(self):
    power = 0
    print "Power =", power
def callback_power_1(self):
    power = 1
    print "Power =", power
#------------------------------------------------
def callback_terrasse_0(self):
    terrasse=0
    print "Terrasse =", terrasse

def callback_terrasse_1(self):
    terrasse=1
    print "Terrasse =", terrasse
#------------------------------------------------
def callback_umseck_0(self):
    umseck=0
    print "umseck =", umseck

def callback_umseck_1(self):
    umseck=1
    print "umseck =", umseck
#------------------------------------------------
def callback_eingang_0(self):
    eingang=0
    print "eingang =", eingang

def callback_eingang_1(self):
    eingang=1
    print "eingang =", eingang
#------------------------------------------------
def callback_strasse_0(self):
    strasse=0
    print "strasse =", strasse

def callback_strasse_1(self):
    strasse=1
    print "strasse =", strasse
#------------------------------------------------
def callback_pieplang_0(self):
    pieplang=0
    print "pieplang =", pieplang

def callback_pieplang_1(self):
    pieplang=1
    print "pieplang =", pieplang
#------------------------------------------------


if __name__ == "__main__":

#Window.size = (800, 480)

#------------------- config data ---------------
HOST = "0.0.0.0"
PORT1 = 47120
PORT2 = 47121
IP_NAME = {
    "192.168.1.202" : [("Umseck  ", "umseck.mp3")],
    "192.168.1.203" : [("Eingang ", "eingang4.mp3"), ("Strasse", "strasse.mp3")],
    "192.168.1.204" : [("Terrasse", "terrasse.mp3")],
    "192.168.1.100" : [("Test ", "umseck.mp3"), ("Test2 ", "terrasse.mp3")],
    "192.168.1.200" : [("Test ", "eingang2.mp3"), ("Test2 ", "strasse.mp3")],
    "192.168.1.201" : ["CCU2"],
    "127.0.0.1" : ["localhost"]
}


#-----------------------------------------------
EVENTS = Queue()
#-----------------------------------------------

server1 = Process (target=socket_server, args=(HOST, PORT1, EVENTS, 1))
server2 = Process (target=socket_server, args=(HOST, PORT2, EVENTS, 2))
handler = Process (target=event_handler, args=(EVENTS, IP_NAME))

server1.start()
server2.start()
handler.start()

MainApp().run()

server1.join()
server2.join()
handler.join()
```

Kivy Lang File:

```
#:kivy 1.8.0
#:import ListItemButton kivy.uix.listview.ListItemButton
#:import ListAdapter kivy.adapters.listadapter.ListAdapter
#:import Rectangle kivy.graphics.vertex_instructions.Rectangle

<ListItemButton>:
selected_color: 0, 0, 1, 1
deselected_color: 0, 0, 0, 1


GridLayout:
spacing: 7
padding: 7
cols: 2
rows: 1
canvas:
    Color:
        rgba: 0.4, 0.8, 0, 1
    Rectangle:
        pos: self.pos
        size: self.size
Label
    text: "Labelein"
GridLayout:
    size_hint_x: 0.6
    spacing: 1
    padding: 1
    cols: 1
    rows: 6
    ToggleButton:
        id: button1
        background_normal:  "button4.png"
        background_down:    "button7.png"
        text: "AUS" if self.state == 'normal' else 'AN'
        bold: True
        on_state:
            if self.state == 'normal': app.callback_power_0()
            else: app.callback_power_1()
        border: 0,0,0,0
    ToggleButton:
        id: button2
        background_normal:  "button4.png"
        background_down:    "button7.png"
        text: "Terrasse" if self.state == 'normal' else 'Terrasse'
        bold: True
        on_state:
            if self.state == 'normal': app.callback_terrasse_0()
            else: app.callback_terrasse_1()
        border: 0,0,0,0
    ToggleButton:
        id: button3
        background_normal:  "button4.png"
        background_down:    "button7.png"
        text: "Umseck" if self.state == 'normal' else 'Umseck'
        bold: True
        on_state:
            if self.state == 'normal': app.callback_umseck_0()
            else: app.callback_umseck_1()
        border: 0,0,0,0
    ToggleButton:
        id: button4
        background_normal:  "button4.png"
        background_down:    "button7.png"
        text: "Eingang" if self.state == 'normal' else 'Eingang'
        bold: True
        on_state:
            if self.state == 'normal': app.callback_eingang_0()
            else: app.callback_eingang_1()
        border: 0,0,0,0
    ToggleButton:
        id: button5
        background_normal:  "button4.png"
        background_down:    "button7.png"
        text: "Straße" if self.state == 'normal' else 'Straße'
        bold: True
        on_state:
            if self.state == 'normal': app.callback_strasse_0()
            else: app.callback_strasse_1()
        border: 0,0,0,0
    ToggleButton:
        id: button6
        background_normal:  "button4.png"
        background_down:    "button7.png"
        text: "Piep kurz" if self.state == 'normal' else 'Piep lang'
        bold: True
        on_state:
            if self.state == 'normal': app.callback_pieplang_0()
            else: app.callback_pieplang_1()
        border: 0,0,0,0
```

***SOLUTION***

Problem can be solved by using `multiprocessing.manager`. Another way - thats how I did it, is to use shard memory for the variable by using `n.value`:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    power = Value('b', 1)
    ....
    handler = Process (target=event_handler, args=(power, ... #handing over to process
```

Kivy Class is using *.value to set variables in shared memory

```
class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file("beedo_111_manager.kv")

    def callback_power_0(self):
        power.value = 0
        print "Power =", power.value
    def callback_power_1(self):
        power.value = 1
        print "Power =", power.value
    ....
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question contains a large amount of code. Please check out [ask] and [mcve] to see how to improve your question.

Comment: Another general comment: do not use global variables. Instead, use [data attributes](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#instance-objects)

Comment: `multiprocessing` doesn't work this way. Each `Process` is a separate Python interpreter, changing global state in one doesn't affect the other. You can use the `multiprocessing.Manager` class to create objects which can be shared between `Process`es.

Comment: Wow Jesus! - thank you Ryan. I will look up now how to use multiprocessing.Manager .

Comment: While looking on python.org on how to use the manager, I found "16.6.1.4. Sharing state between processes". I managed to put the variables in the shared memory with "value". Thank you for your support!